# Is there a way to view the message-id (msgid) when receiving email using the Linux mail command?

Tags: command-line, mail, sendmail

0

I have a program that extracts email from the command line using the `mail` command as follows:

The `Message-ID/msgid` is not part of the resulting email

Is there a way to keep the message-id when reading the email?

We need the message-id since we want to track down certain emails that need investigation

Any help will be great!

```
echo 'p 1-1' | mail -f filename
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that we can get the message-id by issuing the following command:

```
echo 'P 1-1' | mail -f filename
```